# stack pointer and trap frame for thread_creation

Tags: c, multithreading, process, stack

I have a function `clone` which I need to find the address of the arguments on the stack as well as return address, which has the following prototype

```
int clone(void (*fcn) (void*), void *arg, void * stack);
```

I call `clone` from the function `thread_create` which is the same as following:

```
int thread_create(void * (*start_routine) (), void *arg)
{
void *stack=malloc(4096); // I allocate stack for each created thread in the amount of one page
return clone(start_routine,arg,stack);
}
```

I am confused about these pieces of codes. I feel they should be right but not sure. So it would be great if you can confirm if these pieces of codes in clone are right and if not how to correct them?

`1)  process->trap_frame->esp = stack - sizeof (void *)`

`2a) process->trap_frame->return_addr= stack + 4096 - 2*sizeof(void*);`

`2b) process->trap_frame->return_addr= stack + sizeof(stack) - 2*sizeof(void*);`

`3a) process->trap_frame->arguments=stack+4096-sizeof(void*);`

`3b) process->trap_frame->arguments=sizeof(stack)+4096-sizeof(void*);`

Apart from the pieces of code I have written above, how would you find sp(esp), return_addr and arguments in a virtual main in trap_frame?

Comment: Can you not just use your debugger to single-step the code and check the allocated stack to see if your initial TOS trap frame has been correctly loaded?  Later traps from the new thread could, of course, be anywhere on its stack, so I guess you are going to have to resort to some architecture-dependent assembler to get at the SP, then the return address from the thread stack, then some API call index as the last argument of  the call so that it's always in the same relative position to the SP and allowing you to switch to the requested call.

Comment: Well, you are right. This is architecture dependent.